# Application of Mean Value/Rolle's Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives, proof-writing

**Question**

Let $f$ be a differentiable function such that $f'$ is continuous on $[0, 1]$ and $M$ the maximum value of $|f'(x)|$ on $[0, 1]\ $. Prove that, if $f(0) = f(1) = 0$, then $$\int^{1}_{0} |f(x)| \mathrm {d}x \leq \frac M 4\ .$$

---

I have stared long and hard at this question for quite some time, but I am not sure where to even begin. Since I see that the endpoints are given, I think of MVT, but since they are also equal, I think of Rolle's Theorem too. These are just my intuitions - they could be wrong. Moreover, the moduli of $f'(x)$ and $f(x)$ are throwing me off. Any hints/suggestions on how to approach this question would be greatly appreciated :)

P.S. I am only taking an introductory calculus module in college, so the tools at my disposal are, roughly, IVT, MVT and Rolle's Theorem.

Comment: Hint : you have $f(x)|=f(x)-f(0)=xf^{\prime}(c)$ for a $c$, hence $|f(x)|\leq Mx$, and integrate from $0$ to $1/2$. After, you have $f(x)=f(x)-f(1)=...$

Comment: @Kelenner Thank you for the hint, but it is not very helpful as I am still just as lost... Why does $f(x) - f(0)$ = $xf'(c)$ for some $c$?

Comment: This is  a particular case of the theorem that say $f(b)-f(a)=(b-a)f^{\prime}(c)$ for some $c$

Comment: @Kelenner Oh. Okay I get the first part of your hint now, but I have two questions. Firstly, why should that imply that $|f(x)| \leq Mx$? And secondly, why integrate from $0$ to $\frac 1 2$? Where did you get the limits of integration from i.e. how did the $\frac 1 2$ appear?

Comment: You have from $f(x)=f(x)-f(0)$ that $|f(x)|\leq Mx$ as in my first comment. What do you get if you integrate from $0$ to $1/2$ ? Once done, use $f(x)-f(1)=...$ to get $|f(x)|\leq M(1-x)$, and now integrate from $1/2$ to $1$.

Comment: ?? you have $[f^{\prime}(t)[\leq M$ for all $t$ by hypothesis...

Comment: @Kelenner Yes. Haha. I deleted my comment because I realised that I was being stupid, but you replied too quickly. Okay! I get it now! So just to be clear, there is no particular reason for integrating from $0$ to $\frac 1 2$ for the first one and $\frac 1 2$ to $1$ for the second right? It is just "convenient" because the $\frac M 4$ comes out eventually?

Comment: Yes, it is just "convenient"  to obtain the proof... I must go bye

Comment: @Kelenner Thank you so much for your time! Have a good day!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use Kelenner's hint to solve this problem.

We have
$$|f(x)| = |f(x) - f(0)| = |f(1)-f(x)|\text{.}$$
and by the MVT, for any $0 < x \leq 1$, there exists a $c_1 \in (0, 1)$ satisfying
$$f^{\prime}(c_1) = \dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x - 0} = \dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x} \implies |f(x)-f(0)| = |f^{\prime}(c_1) \cdot x| = |f^{\prime}(c_1)||x|\leq M|x|\text{.}$$
Thus we have
$$|f(x)| = |f(x) - f(0)| \leq M|x|\text{.}$$
Additionally, by the MVT, for any $0 \leq x < 1$, there exists a $c_2 \in (0, 1)$ satisfying
$$f^{\prime}(c_2) = \dfrac{f(1)-f(x)}{1-x} = \dfrac{-f(x)}{1-x} = \dfrac{f(x)}{x-1} \implies |f(x)| = |f^{\prime}(c_2) \cdot (x-1)| = |f^{\prime}(c_2)||x-1| \leq M|x-1|\text{.}$$
Hence,
$$|f(x)| \leq M|x-1|\text{.}$$
Thus
$$\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|\text{ d}x \leq \int_{0}^{1/2}M|x|\text{ d}x+\int_{1/2}^{1}M|x-1|\text{ d}x = \dfrac{M}{8} + \dfrac{M}{8} = \dfrac{M}{4}\text{.}$$

Answer (score 1):

The rigourous proof given above proves the inequality, but I wish to give a little handwaiving argument that might give insight into why this should be true.

The problem is effectively about maximizing the area under a function in the interval $[-1,1]$ that satisfies the given conditions.

So in this interval we know that the functions end points are at $x=0$ and $x=1$ intersecting the $x$ axis.

In the interval $(0,1) $ The function has infinite possibilities, but it has to be differentiable, $f'(x)$ has to be continuous and satisfy $max |f' (x)|=M $ .

Given these 3 conditions we need to maximize the area under the curve.